# Change class of columns according to a vector

Tags: r, format, apply

I have 2 dataframes:

- The main one `df`
- Another dataframe `tmp` which describes columns types of `df` and the **New_format** on which columns should be converted

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                 var2 = c(1,2,3), 
                 var3 = c("d", "e", "f"))

tmp <- data.frame(Variable = c("var1", "var2", "var3"), 
                  Format = c("character", "numeric", "character"),
                  New_format = c("character", "integer", "factor"))
```

I'd like to convert types of columns where **New_format** is different from **Format**. I've struggled a lot by using lapply function but did not manage to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `readr::type_convert()`

```
library(tidyverse)

types <- paste(map_chr(tmp$New_format, ~str_sub(., 1,1)), collapse = "")

new_df <- type_convert(df, types, guess_integer = T)

str(new_df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ var1: chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ var2: int  1 2 3
 $ var3: Factor w/ 3 levels "d","e","f": 1 2 3
```

This function requires that the type specifications are passed in either as a `cols()` statement, or as a string with the new column type indicated by a single letter (e.g. "c" for character, "f" for factor, and so on).

So either just rename `New_format` labels to their single-letter versions ("c", "i", "f"), or you can use `str_sub` and `paste` with `tmp` to get the first letters (which `type_convert` wants for the type argument).

Note: Make sure to set `guess_integer = TRUE`, otherwise it will default to type `double` even if you ask for integer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I just realized that I didn't receive notifications email from stackoverflow. Thanks a lot Andrew, it's exaclty what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

You could set up a named mapping between the `New_format` values and corresponding `as.<value>` function, like this:

```
funcs <- list("character"= as.character,"integer"=as.integer, "factor"=as.factor)
```

Then, in a loop, call the function

```
for(i in 1:nrow(tmp)) {
  if(tmp[i,"Format"]!=tmp[i,"New_format"]) {
    df[[tmp[i,"Variable"]]] <-funcs[[tmp[i,"New_format"]]](df[[tmp[i,"Variable"]]])   
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks langtang! I thought about doing it with loops but I needed something a bit more readable. Thanks again