# Use a string to assign multiple column types to tibble

Tags: r, readr

The following data has six columns. I want to change all their column types, respectively to factor-factor-factor-int-int-factor.

```
d <- structure(list(a = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9), b = structure(c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), class = "yearmon"), c = c("605417CA", "605417CB", "606822AS", "606822AT", "606822AU", "606822AV", "60683MAB"), d = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), e = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), f = c(2772, 2772, 46367, 46367, 46367, 46367, 47601)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

If I was reading this data from an external file, I would use `vroom(path, col_types = "fffiif")`, and it automatically converts each variable in a string. But here the data is the result of previous computation, so I need to do the conversion myself. Is there a way to change all column types with a simple string, like vroom does?

Things I tried:

- Using `mutate` for each of six variables is quite long.
- Conversions are not one-to-one. For example, "a" and "e" are double, but I want to convert them to factor and int respectively. So `mutate_if` would not work.
- The magrittr package has `set_colnames`, to change colum names by passing a vector of strings. There may be something similar to change column types, but I haven't found anything.
- `readr::type_convert` seems to only apply to columns of type `character`.

I saved the data locally and imported it with `vroom(path, col_types = "fffiif")`, which works perfectly. So the question is to what function I can pass the string `fffiif` to do the conversion once I already have the data.

Comment: With `readr::type_convert`, that doesn't work. Error: col_types must be a single string.

Comment: Apologies, you are right, it must be a list, try: `readr::type_convert(d, col_types = list(col_factor(), col_factor(), col_factor(), col_integer(), col_integer(), col_factor()))`

Comment: This results in the same behavior as `col_types = "fffiif"`, so it just does not modify the data at all. It's as if `type_convert` only used the default behavior and ignored my `col_types` argument.
In particular it converts a char to factor (I guess it's default, I tried with other data), and ignores everything else. It also doesn't convert double to int even if I specify `guess_integer = TRUE`.

Comment: OK, no idea what's happening here, probably best to submit an issue at GitHub https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues I've re-opened the post.

Comment: I tried some other stuff and accidentally stumbled on the error: `type_convert() only converts columns of type 'character'`. Then I guess this is intended behavior of the function, I just didn't understand it from the documentation. Then the question is still whether there exists a function with the behavior of vroom col_types.

Comment: What is the question here: "how to convert columns on already existing dataframe?" or "how to import text file using vroom with predefined column classes?". If it is the first one, then it is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72369777/680068

Comment: It is the former. I know how to easily import data specifying column types as a string, but I don't know how to do that to data I already have. `type_convert` does not do anything at all in my case, so the solution to your linked post does not work. The proof is that the accepted answer's own example doesn't work either. His column `Var2` remains a double even if `type_convert` attempts to convert it to int (or if I specify any other data type for it). Either I'm missing something, or some function internals have changed.

Comment: Did you try the solution by [langtang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72369872/680068) ?

Comment: A loop would work, but at that point I would just do `mutate(a = as.factor(a))` and so on for six columns. I was just wondering if there's a smarter way, since vroom has it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use the *forloop* from [the linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72369872/680068) or *mutate* with *across* to avoid repetition:

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  mutate(across(c(a:c, f), ~ as.factor(.x)),
         across(d:e, ~ as.integer(.x)))

# # A tibble: 7 × 6
#   a     b     c            d     e f    
#   <fct> <fct> <fct>    <int> <int> <fct>
# 1 9     2018  605417CA    NA     0 2772 
# 2 9     2018  605417CB    NA     0 2772 
# 3 9     2018  606822AS    NA     0 46367
# 4 9     2018  606822AT    NA     0 46367
# 5 9     2018  606822AU    NA     0 46367
# 6 9     2018  606822AV    NA     0 46367
# 7 9     2018  60683MAB    NA     0 47601
```

Similar to the linked post, using *lapply*:

```
ff <- list(f = as.factor, i = as.integer)
cc <- unlist(strsplit("fffiif", ""))

d[] <- lapply(seq_along(d), \(i) ff[[ cc[ i ] ]](d[[ i ]]))

sapply(d, class)
#       a         b         c         d         e         f 
# "factor"  "factor"  "factor" "integer" "integer"  "factor"
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I had thought about using `across` to convert a column type for another, ex. all doubles as int, but I had the problem that some doubles need to be int and others need to be factors, so I didn't know how to differentiate. I never thought about using individual variables inside the `across`.

Comment: @FBr see edit, we can use ":" to select range of columns, makes it even simpler.

Comment: I never knew you could use `across(c(a:c))`, I only knew about `across(c(1:3))`. This is very useful for piping in general, thank you.